# Family of 4 (1 adult, 3 kids) dealing with eviction. How to find a new place to live?

Tags: united-states, credit, california, rent, eviction

About 4 years ago I was evicted from our apartment in California. I have been staying with family but this is no longer an option. I have been trying to get a place for us but keep getting denied due to the eviction.

I make enough money to cover the rent and have been at my job for over 10 years. 2 of my kids now have a job but no credit.

What are my options? How can I find a place to live? This is getting extremely frustrating. I am running out of options and time.

p.s. We also have a small family dog.

Answer (score 2):

You can dial 2-1-1 or go to [211.org](http://211.org) to find out about programs that can help you find affordable housing in your area.

Answer (score 1):

Never underestimate the value of a decent trailer park. No joke, in many cases you can rent with cash and no background check. Many people want to scoff at the notion of a trailer park, but my wife's side lived in one for 10 years to save money and now they have multiple properties for living and rentals. Where I live, a suitable house would run you some $1200 a month. A double wide trailer would be close to $400. At a trade off of what? pride? If I was suddenly young again, I'd do it without thinking twice.

To follow up on the notion, I checked craigslist in my area just to confirm and the deals look even better than what I mentioned above. 3 bedroom 2 bath trailers for $1,000 down and $300 a month. You can buy one outright for as low as $2500 and even decent ones with enough room for 4 can be bought for $18k.

You can also consider that people looking to buy trailers tend to be either retired with cash in hand or the exact opposite. Sellers may carry a loan or payment plan. They are used to negotiations on properties like this.

Don't forget that a trailer park does not necessarily mean some scary ghetto. Some of them are really nice and have very warm communities, even amenities. It is definitely worth checking a few out and asking the management what the lot fees are.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been living with a family member's and working full-time along with having two kids working I assume you have saved some money?

I had bad credit and needed a place ASAP, I got in right away by offering to pay 6 months in advance from a private renter. I didn't bother going through a rental agency because I assumed I'd still get turned down despite offering advanced payment.

If you meet with a private renter and let them get to meet you in person then offer 3-6 months down your chances maybe much better than going the traditional route.

I also strongly agree with Kai Qing and second his recommendation of looking at mobile homes. If you don't have funds to pre-pay for a number of months the mobile home/trailer park route is the best solution in my opinion. I say this because when I was younger I bought and rented low end mobile homes. Cash worked fine and I never credit checked anyone, I used my intuition on whether I could trust them paying me.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

A lawyer could be hired to sue the properties that have turned-down rental applications.

A real estate agent could be hired to find a rental.

One year's rent could be offered in advance.

Financing of a mobile home or condo could be attempted. Of course the mobile home has monthly lot rent while the condo has monthly homeowner's fees.

An extended-stay motel might be found.

A rental directly from a property owner might be found. Search with websites.

A "contract for deed" might be found. This is a rental that doesn't include maintenance because it is rent-to-own. This situation is risky unless there is someone in the family that repairs houses.

Comment: *A lawyer could be hired to sue the properties that have turned-down rental applications* Better spend your time and effort on moving forward instead of (a) risking not winning those cases, (b) winning and having to deal with bad relations with the property owners, and (c) feeding your frustration.

Comment: If a person's rights are violated then that person and many other people will benefit from legal defense of the rights. Of course even reputable law firms charge up to 60% of a settlement. But the litigation is not necessarily for a settlement, it could be just to change an administrative action. Then "pro bono" refers to legal services that are donated.

Comment: I very much doubt there is a good case to sue these landlords if the reason for refusing to offer a lease is a known history of eviction (particularly if it was at fault in some way). Though I dont know the OPs local laws.

Comment: The same way a bank can and probably should, turn down a credit card to someone with a sub-500 FICO, a landlord’s best defense to avoid a non paying tenant is to screen them and not accept tenant with an eviction on their record. They are not a protected class.

Comment: Sure enough, I'm not expecting a mistake by the rental agent but I am saying that legal advice is available.